# Creating a dataframe of rows of many fields in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I need to create a DataFrame whose rows include around 30 members (int, double and string). What I did was to create one row of DataFrame and it works:

```
var res_df = sc.parallelize(Seq((
  results_combine(0),
  results_combine(1),
  results_combine(2),
  results_combine(3),
  results_combine(4),
  results_combine(5),
  results_combine(6),
  results_combine(7),
  results_combine(8),
  results_combine(9),
  results_combine(10)
))).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k")
```

However, when I tried to add more elements to the tuple inside of the Seq, I got an error because of 22 element limit. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

So here's an example using [explicit Row and schema definition APIs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema).

The (mildy) annoying part is setting up the schema object. See [StructField](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField) and [StructType](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType).

Hopefully this works under Scala 2.10.x!

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame,Row}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row}

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

scala> val alphabet = ('a' to 'z').map( _ + "" ) // for column labels
alphabet: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z)

scala> val row1 = Row( 1 to 26 : _* )
row1: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]

scala> val row2 = Row( 26 to 1 by -1 : _* )
row2: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [26,25,24,23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

scala> val schema = StructType( alphabet.map( label =>  StructField(label, IntegerType, false) ) )
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(a,IntegerType,false), StructField(b,IntegerType,false), StructField(c,IntegerType,false), StructField(d,IntegerType,false), StructField(e,IntegerType,false), StructField(f,IntegerType,false), StructField(g,IntegerType,false), StructField(h,IntegerType,false), StructField(i,IntegerType,false), StructField(j,IntegerType,false), StructField(k,IntegerType,false), StructField(l,IntegerType,false), StructField(m,IntegerType,false), StructField(n,IntegerType,false), StructField(o,IntegerType,false), StructField(p,IntegerType,false), StructField(q,IntegerType,false), StructField(r,IntegerType,false), StructField(s,IntegerType,false), StructField(t,IntegerType,false), StructField(u,IntegerType,false), StructField(v,IntegerTyp...

scala> val rdd = hiveContext.sparkContext.parallelize( Seq( row1, row2 ) )
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = ParallelCollectionRDD[5] at parallelize at <console>:23

scala> val df = hiveContext.createDataFrame( rdd, schema )
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int, e: int, f: int, g: int, h: int, i: int, j: int, k: int, l: int, m: int, n: int, o: int, p: int, q: int, r: int, s: int, t: int, u: int, v: int, w: int, x: int, y: int, z: int]

scala> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|  g|  h|  i|  j|  k|  l|  m|  n|  o|  p|  q|  r|  s|  t|  u|  v|  w|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15| 16| 17| 18| 19| 20| 21| 22| 23| 24| 25| 26|
| 26| 25| 24| 23| 22| 21| 20| 19| 18| 17| 16| 15| 14| 13| 12| 11| 10|  9|  8|  7|  6|  5|  4|  3|  2|  1|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick and dirty function that takes a `Seq` of tuples and builds your schema based on it. The idea is that you take your field names and `zip` them with your first row of data. The function uses the type of the data to build the correct `StructField`.

```
def toStructType(schema: Seq[(String,Any)]) : StructType = {
  StructType(schema.map(v => {
    StructField(v._1, v._2 match {
      case i: Int => IntegerType
      case l: Long => LongType
      case s: String => StringType
      case d: Double => DoubleType
      case f: Float => FloatType
      case x => StringType
    })
  })) 
}

var pseudoSchema = Seq[(String,Any)](("test", 123))

toStructType(pseudoSchema)
// res17: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(test,IntegerType,true))
```

I'm probably missing some types, but you get the idea. The following gets you 26 columns, named a-z, expecting `Ints`

```
toStructType(('a' to 'z').map(_.toString).map((_,1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is just to [use case classes to define the contents of your rows](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#inferring-the-schema-using-reflection). Presuming a SparkContext `sc` and HIveContext `hiveContext` are already established, and omitting some ugly log messages...

```
scala> case class Alphabet (
     | a : Int = 1,
     | b : Int = 2,
     | c : Int = 3,
     | d : Int = 4,
     | e : Int = 5,
     | f : Int = 6,
     | g : Int = 7,
     | h : Int = 8,
     | i : Int = 9,
     | j : Int = 10,
     | k : Int = 11,
     | l : Int = 12,
     | m : Int = 13,
     | n : Int = 14,
     | o : Int = 15,
     | p : Int = 16,
     | q : Int = 17,
     | r : Int = 18,
     | s : Int = 19,
     | t : Int = 20,
     | u : Int = 21,
     | v : Int = 22,
     | w : Int = 23,
     | x : Int = 24,
     | y : Int = 25,
     | z : Int = 26
     | )
defined class Alphabet

scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize( Seq( new Alphabet() ) )
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Alphabet] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:16

scala> import hiveContext.implicits._
import hiveContext.implicits._

scala> val df = rdd.toDF()
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int, e: int, f: int, g: int, h: int, i: int, j: int, k: int, l: int, m: int, n: int, o: int, p: int, q: int, r: int, s: int, t: int, u: int, v: int, w: int, x: int, y: int, z: int]

scala> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|  d|  e|  f|  g|  h|  i|  j|  k|  l|  m|  n|  o|  p|  q|  r|  s|  t|  u|  v|  w|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10| 11| 12| 13| 14| 15| 16| 17| 18| 19| 20| 21| 22| 23| 24| 25| 26|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

An alternative approach would be to use Spark's [explicit Row and schema definition APIs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem with your approach is that defining a case class with moree than 22 fields is possible in Scala 2.11 but not in version 2.10 which is the version Apache Spark uses. Thus, in spark-shell trying to define that case class gives: "error: Implementation restriction: case classes cannot have more than 22 parameters."

Comment: Case class with more than 22 elements isn't supported in scala 2.10 and I believe the OP is using that version of scala

Comment: Spark libraries are available and supported in Scala 2.11 now, so it works for me... but I guess under 2.10 it wouldn't!

Comment: As a side question, can I change the Scala version that Spark uses?

Comment: I just define an SBT project using 2.11 libraries, and set up the context objects myself, to get 2.11 spark.